# How to play a video chosen from the chooser plugin in Ionic 4?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

In my Ionic 4 app I need to choose a video from the gallery and play it on the canvas using the video tag of HTML5. I am able to pick the file correctly, But I am missing out on what exactly needs to be supplied as the source to the video tag of HTML5.

Snippet from `home.page.ts`:

```
this.chooser.getFile('video/*').then((value:ChooserResult)=>{
    this.fileObject = value;
})
```

Snippet from `home.page.html`:

```
<video controls>
   <source src={{fileObject.dataURI}} type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileChoose is not returning the absolute path of the selected file, it is returning content URI so File Path plugins resolve the native filesystem path for Android content URIs.

HTML code

```
      <ion-button (click)="onClick()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
    Click me
  </ion-button>
  <video controls *ngIf="show">
    <source [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileObject)' type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

TS file

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileChooser, FileChooserOptions } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
const win: any = window;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {
  type: FileChooserOptions;
  fileObject: any;
  show = false;
  constructor(
    private fileChooser: FileChooser,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private filePath: FilePath) {

  }
  onClick() {

    this.fileChooser.open().then((value) => {
      console.log(value);
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(value)
        .then(filePath => {
          console.log(filePath);
          this.show = true;
          this.fileObject = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(filePath);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      // this.fileObject = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Declare plugins into providers app.module.ts

```
 providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    FileChooser,  // new
    FilePath,    // new 
  ],
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a breeze. How do we do it for Ios?

Comment: This plugin will help you for ios    https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-picker